# What's the proper way to read stdin inside parenthesis assignment of 2nd pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

1st style, group 2 pipe to assign, this works:

```
$ myresult1=$(curl -L 'https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=stackoverflow.com' 2>/dev/null | jq '.archived_snapshots.closest.url'); echo "$myresult1"
"http://web.archive.org/web/20160622184546/http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

2nd style, assign only in 2nd pipe, this doesn't work:

```
$ curl -L 'https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=stackoverflow.com' 2>/dev/null | myresult2=$(jq '.archived_snapshots.closest.url'); echo "$myresult2"

$
```

So I'm wondering if it is possible to make the 2nd style work, i.e. if I can read stdin inside parenthesis assignment.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do it the second way?

Comment: @123 Because 2nd way no doubt is more flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second command works, the issue is you are using `bash` or whatever shell that put all pipelines components in a subshell. `myresult2` is properly set but the variable is immediately out of scope unless you stay in the same subshell like here:

```
curl -L 'https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=stackoverflow.com' \
     2>/dev/null | {
     myresult2=$(jq '.archived_snapshots.closest.url'); echo "$myresult2" ; }
```

If you run this command under `ksh`, the variable assignment will be done in the topmost shell so will work as expected.

Alternatively, you might set the lastpipe option to get `ksh` behavior under `bash`:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
```

If you want this to work in an interactive session, you should also disable job control:

```
set +m
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought jq failed to read stdin inside assignment, without realize that i'm doing echo outside of pipe subshell.